# Visual Studio 2010 TFS Solution checked out and hard drive broken

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I am working on a group project in Visual Studio and using TFS for source control. I was working on the project from my laptop and the hard drive broke. Now the solution is eternally checked out by my laptop user. How can I clear the checkout from my laptop? None of the changes are needed, I have the log in credentials, and I can still get into Windows on the laptop (the secondary hard drive broke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is using the tf.exe command line utility.

Find the exact workspace, if not already known, using:

```
tf workspaces /computer:computername
```

Then remove that workspace with:

```
tf workspaces /remove:workspacename
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3.aspx